# What is the meaning of CTOR?

Tags: c#

In a lot of C# files I see regions tags(?) that are named CTOR or ctor. What's the meaning of ctor? Why is such a region called ctor?

Answer (score 369, accepted):

It's just shorthand for "constructor" - and it's what the constructor is called in IL, too. For example, open up Reflector and look at a type and you'll see members called `.ctor` for the various constructors.

Comment: why it's called .ctor? What is the meaning of (.) dot in front?

Comment: @isuruceanu: I suspect it's to show that it's a reserved name. Just a guess though.

Comment: What about xxx.#.ctor() ? , it fails my FxCop execution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024149/fxcop-exception-bad-method-type-parameter-in-position-0

Comment: @AndreasBlomqvist: What do you mean by "what about"? It's not clear what you're asking me.

Comment: I am trying to get a FxCop run to work. The offending code looks like somepackage.StructureMapBootstrapper+ExecutingAssemblyRegistry.#.ctor() and I was wondering what the "#" mean. Clearly FxCop cant handle the "#" sign. Not so familiar with C# and not the author of the code. The code contains " Scan(x =>" section which I suspect is the cause of the "#" sign.

Comment: @AndreasBlomqvist: Okay, but I'm not sure what that has to do with this question/answer. It sounds like it's solely about FxCop really.

Comment: How is it said? Does ctor rhyme with Skeet-er? Did you make the abbreviation? Or is it "cutter"?

Comment: @Jessy: I've rarely heard it pronounced, but I'd pronounce it "see-tor".

Comment: When using reflection to call a constructor, the constructor is also specified as ".ctor"

Comment: @isuruceanu Anything starts with "." in the IL is metadata.

Answer (score 50):

Usually this region should contains the constructors of the class

Comment: "should contain" -- does that mean a .ctor is not necessarily always reference a constructor? Or just that it does not always reference the constructor of a class (because it could reference a struct for example)?

Answer (score 45):

To expand a little more, there are two kinds of constructors: instance initializers (.ctor), type initializers (.cctor). Build the code below, and explore the IL code in ildasm.exe. You will notice that the static field 'b' will be initialized through .cctor() whereas the instance field will be initialized through .ctor()

```
internal sealed class CtorExplorer
{
   protected int a = 0;
   protected static int b = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Type "ctor" and press the **TAB** key twice this will add the default constructor automatically

Comment: In VS2013 (and using R# 2016.1) I only have to press tab once.  Not sure about other versions of VS/R#

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Not an answer, so downvoted. But an interesting thing to know, so undownvoted. :-)

Comment: Not an answer; but still a interesting fact to know, believe it deserve an upvote; :)