# C# System.Exception StackTrace getting truncated

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

For some reason the StackTrace in my Exceptions are getting truncated. The first part of the StackTrace will get recorded, followed by ".." followed by the last part of the StackTrace to look like this:

`at F503100.ViewModels.ShellViewModel..ctor(IDbService dbService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, ILoggerService logger) in C:\AProjects\bfn\L503574_8113851\Administrator\F503100\ViewModels\ShellViewModel.cs:line 90`

At first I thought it was the logger, but when I placed a break point in Visual Studio and looked at the exception, the value in the StackTrace property was truncated as well.

I am compiling in Debug mode with "Debugging information" set to "Full" in the Advanced Build Settings.

Comment: Are you sure that's not the constructor `ctor` for the `ShellViewModel` class?

Comment: At least related: ["What is the meaning of CTOR?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614099/what-is-the-meaning-of-ctor)

Comment: A constructor is often abbreviated `.ctor` (it dates back to C++ conventions).  My guess is that `F503100.ViewModels.ShellViewModel..ctor` is the constructor for the `F503100.ViewModels.ShellViewModel` class

Comment: Sorry, .ctor is the constructor in this case. I was just testing some logging functionality and I was expecting the stacktrace to be longer. My bad. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of CTOR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614099/what-is-the-meaning-of-ctor)